# Does anyone know how to run solr, django-haystack through twittertype head?

Tags: solr, django-haystack, twitter-typeahead

I have been googling for 2 days now and I can not find out how to plug my results from haystack-django into twitter typeahead.js. All I see are examples that are using fake data that is stored in an array and then pulling from that data.

this is what I tried

```
  $(function() {
   $("#input-field").typeahead({
       source:function(query,process) {
           $.ajax({
           type: "GET",
           url: "/posts/search_f/",
           data: {
               'search_text': $('#search').val(),
               'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
           },
           success: searchSuccess,
           dataType: 'html'
       });
      }
   })
});


function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

which I tried modifying from this

```
$(function(){

        $('#search').keyup(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/posts/search_f/",
                data: {
                    'search_text': $('#search').val(),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: searchSuccess,
                dataType: 'html'
            });
        });
    });

    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#search-results').html(data);
    }
```

but it does not work. If someone knows a tutorial that explains this or can offer guidance I would appreciate it thanks.

Comment: What is the format of the JSON returned by the service at `/posts/search_f`?  Give an example of the actual data.

Comment: Use your browser dev tools to capture the GET call to the service.  Are the parameters correct?  What happens when you make a call to your service via POSTMAN or similar app?